# SimpleDateFormat ParseException : Unparseable date

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute this code:

```
Date date = null;
if (detailsBean.getDiscoveryProjectBean ().getCreatedDate ()==null || 
    detailsBean.getDiscoveryProjectBean ().getCreatedDate ().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    projectDetails.getDiscoveryProject().setCreationTime(new Date());
}
else
{
    try 
    {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat (FormatUtils.simpleFormat).
            parse (detailsBean.getDiscoveryProjectBean ().getCreatedDate ());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new PanDaApplicationException (e.getMessage ());
    }
    projectDetails.getDiscoveryProject().setCreationTime(date);
}
```

in the try block a ParseException exception is thrown. I don't know the cause of that as the code seems fine, however. the definition of the `FormatUtils.simpleFormat` is `public static final String  simpleFormat =   "dd-MMM-yyyy"` and `detailsBean.getDiscoveryProjectBean().getCreatedDate()` have value like `28-Feb-2013`

I really don't have any clues why this exception is thrown and I need help.

Comment: A value *like* "28-Feb-2013" or *exactly* that? And what's your default locale?

Comment: I suppose your default local  is not English you have to change it to en

Comment: Exception message should contain date string the parser failed to parse.  Could you please show us exception message?

Comment: @JonSkeet well exactly that.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes I needed to add locale.US, I think that someone in my team changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is the way that `SimpleDateFormat` uses your default locale - if your locale doesn't use "Feb" as an abbreviated month name, you'll have problems. So if all your data is actually in English, you might want:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(FormatUtils.simpleFormat, Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(...); // See below
date = format.parse(detailsBean.getDiscoveryProjectBean().getCreatedDate());
```

Note the part about setting the time zone. Again, `SimpleDateFormat` will use your system default if you don't specify anything else. (You'll get the instant of "midnight in the specified time zone" as the `Date` value.)

I would also strongly urge you to consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in `Date`/`Calendar` types - it's a much better date/time API.

Answer (score 3):

```
Locale.setDefault (Locale.ROOT);
System.out.println (new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse ("28-Feb-2013"));
Locale.setDefault (Locale.forLanguageTag ("ru"));
System.out.println (new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse ("28-Feb-2013"));
```

For me output is:

```
Thu Feb 28 00:00:00 MSK 2013
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28-Feb-2013"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at DateFormat.main(DateFormat.java:19)
```

So the same date successfully parsed with `ROOT` locale, but failed with Russian.

Comment: It's generally a much better idea (IMO) to just specify the locale for the particular SimpleDateFormat, rather than change the default.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just demonstrated how improper default locale can cause such exception.  Of cause there are several ways how to fix this.

Comment: The trouble is, when you only mention one of these, it's reasonable for the OP to infer that you believe that's the best way of doing it.